# Modifying a large set of objects using JPA / EclipseLink

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I need to iterate 50k objects and change some fields in them.
I'm limited in memory so I don't want to bring all 50k objects into memory at once.
I thought doing it with the following code using cursor, but I was wondering whether all the objects I've processes using the cursor are left in the Entity Manager cache.
The reason I don't want to do it with offset and limit is because the database needs to work much harder since each page is a complete new query.
From previous experience once the Entity manager cache gets bigger, updates become real slow.
So usually I call flush and clear after every few hundreds of updates.
The problem here is that flushing / clearing will break the cursor.
I will be happy to learn the best approach of updating a large set of objects without loading them all into memory.
Additional information on how EclipseLink cursor works in such scenraio will be valuable too.

```
JpaQuery<T> jQuery = (JpaQuery<T>) query;
jQuery.setHint(QueryHints.RESULT_SET_TYPE, ResultSetType.ForwardOnly)
              .setHint(QueryHints.SCROLLABLE_CURSOR, true);
Cursor cursor = jQuery.getResultCursor();
Iterator<MyObj> cursorIterator = cursor.iterator();
while (cursorIterator.hasNext()) {
      MyObj myObj = cursorIterator.next();
      ChangeMyObj(myObj);
}
cursor.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [pagination](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#setMaxResults%28int%29) + `entityManager.clear()` after each page. Also execute every page in a single transaction OR you will have to create/get a new EntityManager after an exception occurs (ar least with Hibernate: the EntityManager instance could be in an inconsistent state after an exception).

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample code:

```
    List results;
    int index= 0;
    int max = 100;
    do {
    Query query= manager.createQuery("JPQL QUERY");
query.setMaxResults(max).
setFirstResult(index);
 results = query.getResultList( );
    Iterator it = results.iterator( );
    while (it.hasNext( )) {
    Object c = (Object)it.next( );

    }
entityManager.clear( );
index = index + results.getSize( );
} while (results.size( ) > 0);
```